# "spawn npm.cmd ENOENT" when running "amplify publish"

Tags: aws-amplify

I have a simple React application with an Amplify configuration. When I try to publish it using  Amplify (Mac) it ends with the following error:

```
❯ amplify publish
✔ Successfully pulled backend environment dev from the cloud.

Current Environment: dev

| Category | Resource name                | Operation | Provider plugin   |
| -------- | ---------------------------- | --------- | ----------------- |
| Api      | sls-demo-twitter-state-api-2 | No Change |                   |
| Hosting  | amplifyhosting               | No Change | awscloudformation |

No changes detected
Publish started for amplifyhosting
command execution terminated with error
An error occurred during the publish operation: spawn npm.cmd ENOENT
```

The same configuration runs without any problems on my other client (Windows). Actually Amplify tries to build the app first and this step does not work. I cannot find reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

"amplify publish" basically runs the build & start commands from amplify project configuration,
that you can reconfigure using `amplify configure project`.

I hope in your machine(Mac) `npm is missing`.

Install node `brew install node`  and run `amplify publish`

Comment: No, it's not a problem with the missing `npm` installation. It would be great if the world was that simple :).